# Why isn't Rollbar catching my exceptions in my Django/Python app?

Tags: python, django, logging, error-handling, rollbar

**Technologies and Applications used**: Rollbar, Django 1.7, Python 3.4

So, I'm following the official documentation found here for integrating Rollbar into a python and Django based application: https://github.com/rollbar/pyrollbar. Which includes: pip installing rollbar, adding the middleware class and creating the Rollbar dictionary configuration in a settings file, etc.

Just to test things out I added the example they provided in their docs to one of my views, and Rollbar/Django works fine (i.e. Rollbar registers the exception and the exception is sent to my Rollbar account in the cloud):

```
try:
    main_app_loop()
except IOError:
    rollbar.report_message('Got an IOError in the main loop', 'warning')
except:
   # catch-all
   rollbar.report_exc_info()
```

But, for example, in one of my template files I misspell a block tag and get an error via Django's default error logging system. However, Rollbar doesn't record the error and/or it isn't sent to my Rollbar account in the cloud. Is that because Rollbar has to be integrated manually via some kind of try, catch scenario? Or can Rollbar just grab errors by default without having to write a try, catch?

There is no other documentation I kind find for integrating Rollbar into a Django project other than what is found on the above link, so I'm not sure what to do next. Anyone else run into this or know what the issue might be?

Comment: Take a look to this: https://github.com/rollbar/pyrollbar/issues/21